# How to run a Fortran Executable file, which generally runs in Ubuntu Terminal, within a Python-3 script?

Tags: scripts, python, gnome-terminal, python3, fortran

I have a Fortran Executable file named `chuck` in the folder `/home/debajyoti/chuckDir/`.

The program `chuck` do is like, it takes an input file `inputfile.txt` and an output file `outputfile.txt` and calculates on the data from `inputfile.txt` and writes the output in the file `outputfile.txt`.

I to do all these calculations with the following steps in **Ubuntu Terminal**:

`~$ cd chuckDir`

`~/chuckDir$ ./chuck <inputfile.txt> outputfile.txt`

NOW I want to run `chuck` and do all these within a `Python Script`. The purpose of the `Python3 Script` is, it takes the data from the `outputfile.txt` to Plot. Now my question is how can I run chuck within the `Python3 Script` itself?

Comment: Have you considered calling the executable and such with a `subprocess` call?

Comment: @ThomasWard No I haven't tried. Please tell me the steps in details. Thank you.

Comment: I can only give you the basics, more advanced execution usage, etc. will require separate programming-specific threads because at that point it's a pure programming issue and not an Ubuntu one

Comment: Mote the question has been crossposted to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729518/how-to-run-an-executable-file-which-is-generally-run-in-ubuntu-terminal-within and has according to the comment a god anser at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106720/python-subprocess-call-check-call-and-returncode-to-find-if-a-command-exist

Answer (score 0):

This is usually where `subprocess` is a very useful bit of Pythonic magic.

Assuming the input file is named `inputfile.txt` you can do this and throw stderr output on error, and stdout on successful run:

```
import subprocess as sp  # I do this for shortening things later on
import shlex

# Run the program you want with the arguments you want split properly (thanks to shlex.split to making it so sp.run works right); store stdout and stderr results as well
chuck = sp.run(shlex.split('/full/path/to/chuck /full/path/to/inputfile.txt /full/path/for/outputfile.txt'), stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

if chuck.returncode != 0:
    # If a program exits on an error or fail condition its exitcode is usually not 0
    raise RuntimeError("Chuck did not run right!\n\n{}".format(chuck.stderr))

print(chuck.stdout)
```

However, you need to really make sure that you are using proper paths for your files and the `chuck` executable in this, and use full directory paths.  This is the basic code you'll need to work with it and to execute `chuck` with proper paths.  You should use fully qualified paths on disk where possible, by the way.

Essentially the extra steps to check the returncode, stderr output, and stdout output from the program are debugging steps.  If the program runs as intended, you will get an outputfile.txt where you specify it to go.